# Number of "connected" designs in a voxel grid

Tags: combinatorics

I am curious whether there is an answer to this question: Say you have an $n^2$ voxel space (2D) where each voxel can take either a value of 0 or 1 (binary encoding). The number of possible designs in that space is $2^{n^2}$. However, I'm only interested in the number of designs that are "connected," meaning that voxels with a value of 1 have to share an edge in 2D. If the number of components (graph theory) is 2 or more then it is not included in the number. Similarly, for a three-dimensional space the number of possible designs would be $2^{n^3}$, but how many of those are connected? Essentially, what I'm trying to find out is how large the "connected space" is compared to the full space.

Comment: what is a "voxel space"? Also, what do you mean by "connected"?

Comment: By space I mean the total number of possible combinations of voxels with values 0 and 1 (thus $2^n$ in 2D). By connected I mean that voxels with a value of 1 have to share an edge in 2D or a face in 3D.

Comment: I suspect the number of connected designs becomes a very small fraction of total designs.  Is the empty grid connected?

Comment: By empty grid I assume you refer to all voxels with a value of 0. This is not connected. However, if you have an almost empty grid with 1 voxel that has a value of 1, then it's connected.

Comment: Do you think this could be generalized by a formula for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A140517 for a related problem: the number of connected regions which do not have any holes. They struggle to compute this up to a 25 x 25 grid, so no formula is likely. They do not even provide an asymptotic formula.

Comment: Then I get 1,13,320 for the first three terms. For n=1 the filled square is connected. For n=2 the only ones not connected are the empty grid and two diagonal squares. For n=3 we first count the disconnected ones that have the central square.  There are $15$ with no center side squares, $12$ with one center side square and $4$ with two center side squares, so there are $2^8-31=225$ connected ones with the center square.  If the center square is blank we can get a connected grid by choosing one of the eights squares in the outer ring to start on and one (maybe the same) to end on, for $64$.

Comment: This gives $1,13,289$ and none of the entries in OEIS seem to apply